# What is the difference between a CloudWatch Alarm and a CloudWatch Event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the difference between a CloudWatch Alarm and a CloudWatch Event? For me both seem to respond on a certain metric and trigger something on their target? What are important differences?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Some key differences:

- Events can self-trigger based on a schedule; alarms don't do this
- Alarms invoke actions only for sustained changes
- Alarms watch a single *metric* and respond to changes in that metric; events can respond to *actions* (such as a lambda being created or some other change in your AWS environment)
- Alarms can be added to CloudWatch dashboards, but events cannot
- Events are processed by targets, with many more options than the actions an alarm can trigger

Event:

> Amazon CloudWatch Events delivers a near real-time stream of system
>   events that describe changes in Amazon Web Services (AWS) resources.
>   Using simple rules that you can quickly set up, you can match events
>   and route them to one or more target functions or streams. CloudWatch
>   Events becomes aware of operational changes as they occur. CloudWatch
>   Events responds to these operational changes and takes corrective
>   action as necessary, by sending messages to respond to the
>   environment, activating functions, making changes, and capturing state
>   information.
>
> You can also use CloudWatch Events to schedule automated actions that
>   self-trigger at certain times using cron or rate expressions.

Alarm:

> You can create a CloudWatch alarm that watches a single CloudWatch
>   metric or the result of a math expression based on CloudWatch metrics.
>   The alarm performs one or more actions based on the value of the
>   metric or expression relative to a threshold over a number of time
>   periods. The action can be an Amazon EC2 action, an Amazon EC2 Auto
>   Scaling action, or a notification sent to an Amazon SNS topic.
>
> Alarms invoke actions for sustained state changes only. CloudWatch
>   alarms don't invoke actions simply because they are in a particular
>   state, the state must have changed and been maintained for a specified
>   number of periods.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html
- https://www.edureka.co/blog/amazon-cloudwatch-monitoring-tool/

Comment: Apparently as of two weeks after this answer was written, CloudWatch Alarms were updated to automatically trigger a CloudWatch Event (now called EventBridge Event) upon every change of Alarm state: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-cloudwatch-sends-alarm-state-change-events-amazon-eventbridge/ So seemingly now (by using a CloudWatch Event as intermediary) CloudWatch Alarms can trigger all of the same actions that CloudWatch events can? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-eventbridge.html